# unable to locate elements in popup-window though switched focus to it, selenium

Tags: selenium

Tried to practice selenium on indeed.ca. The following describes my steps:

1. Openeded 'indeed.ca'
2. Typed 'IT support' in text area for searching
3. clicked on first job among the group of published jobs
4. clicked on "Apply Now' button,
5. a window-pop has come which has the fields to enter data relevant to labels like 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email' and a button 'choose file' to upload a resume.

After I switched the driver focus to 'window-pop', I am unable to locate elements.

Here are all the links used:

1. https://www.indeed.ca/
2. https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=it+support&l=Toronto%2C+ON (with search criteria IT SUPPORT)
3. https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=it%20support&l=Toronto%2C%20ON&vjk=837c0cbbf26a68a7 (link for the window after clicking first option in the jobs list)
4. I shared the [screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn1N6.png) for window-pop after clicking on 'Apply Now'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The fields are inside nested iframes.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id('indeed-ia-1532701404288-0-modal-iframe'))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('frame'))

first_name = driver.find_element_by_id('input-applicant.name')
```

Comment: Isn't it bad to use `indeed-ia-1532701404288-0-modal-iframe` this id?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, after clicking on **Apply Now** **button** :

There are two iframes , in order to interact with newly opened pop up, you will have to switch to both of the frames.

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=it%20support&l=Toronto%2C%20ON&vjk=837c0cbbf26a68a7")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

apply_now = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Apply Now']/ancestor::a")))
apply_now.click()  

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.indeed-apply-bd>iframe"))) 

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src^='https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/resumeapply?']"))  

Name = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "input-applicant.name")))  
Name.send_keys("Vijay")
```